# Ayuda Java 8 Lambda Eclipse

Tags: java, lambda

Tengo una clase inicilizadora `código`, donde crea un objeto de la clase List utilizando `Collections`, con una simple expresion Lambda que no me esta imprimiendo el resultado.
Que puedo estar haciendo mal en la expresion Lambda? Ya me asegure que mi version es 8, tambien me parecio raro, que ECLIPSE cuando invocaba al medoto `getApellido()` no activaba Intellisense. Gracias

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Persona> personList = Init.createSortList();

        System.out.println("Ordenacion Ascendente");

        Collections.sort(personList, (Persona person1, Persona person2) -> person1.getApellido().compareTo(person2.getApellido()));

        for(Persona e: personList) {
            e.imprimirPersona();
        }

    }

    static List<Persona> createSortList() {
        List<Persona> ListaPersonas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

        String nombre = "David";
        String apellido = "Romera";
        int edad = 24;
        String email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        String telefono = "115821439";
        String direccion = "Arevalo 2364";
        Persona person1 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);


        nombre = "Adolfo";
        apellido = "Austracio";
        edad = 24;
        email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        telefono = "115821439";
        direccion = "Arevalo 2364";

        Persona person2 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);

        nombre = "Zambrano";
        apellido = "Roberto";
        edad = 24;
        email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        telefono = "115821439";
        direccion = "Arevalo 2364";

        Persona person3 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);

        return ListaPersonas;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Habría que ver el código de la clase Persona, pero lo que te falta es añadir a las personas a la lista:

```
listaPersonas.add(person1);
listaPersonas.add(person2);
listaPersonas.add(person3);
```

Aquí el código completo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Init {
    public static class Persona {
        private String apellido;
        public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, String email, String telefono, String direccion) {
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }
        public String getApellido() {
            return this.apellido;
        }
        public void imprimirPersona() {
            System.out.println(this.apellido);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Persona> personList = Init.createSortList();
        System.out.println("Ordenacion Ascendente");
        Collections.sort(personList, (Persona person1, Persona person2) - > person1.getApellido().compareTo(person2.getApellido()));
        for (Persona e: personList) {
            e.imprimirPersona();
        }
    }

    static List<Persona> createSortList() {
        List<Persona> ListaPersonas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        String nombre = "David";
        String apellido = "Romera";
        int edad = 24;
        String email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        String telefono = "115821439";
        String direccion = "Arevalo 2364";
        Persona person1 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);
        ListaPersonas.add(person1);

        nombre = "Adolfo";
        apellido = "Austracio";
        edad = 24;
        email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        telefono = "115821439";
        direccion = "Arevalo 2364";

        Persona person2 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);
        ListaPersonas.add(person2);
        nombre = "Zambrano";
        apellido = "Roberto";
        edad = 24;
        email = "gonzalo29031978@hotmail.com";
        telefono = "115821439";
        direccion = "Arevalo 2364";

        Persona person3 = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, email, telefono, direccion);
        ListaPersonas.add(person3);
        return ListaPersonas;

    }

}
```

Comment: Me faltaba eso! De 10! Porque pensas que eclipse no trabaja con Intellisense cuando invoco al metodo getApellido()? Gracias!

Comment: @Gonzalo puede que Eclipse no soporte aún esas funcionalidades. ¿Has probado con otro IDE como Netbeans o IntelliJ Idea? Para este tipo de cosas suelen ser más avanzados que Eclipse.

Comment: hola @ordago gracias por el comentario, es posible que Eclipse no lo soporte, lo probare en Netbeans o IntelliJ Idea! Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Tu lambda esta aparentemente bien, lo que ocurre es que en tu método createSortList(), estás creando tus personas pero te olvidas de agregarlos a la lista, por lo tanto la lista está vacía y no te imprime nada.

Comment: Me faltaba eso! De 10! Porque pensas que eclipse no trabaja con Intellisense cuando invoco al metodo getApellido()?

Comment: Lo del Intellisense no lo sé, debería hacerlo.